# KDE display not working on NixOS - Thinkpad P15 Gen 2, NVIDIA RTX A4000

Tags: kde, nixos, thinkpad

I'm trying to install NixOS on a new Thinkpad P15 Gen 2, and I can't get the desktop environment to show anything on my screen. Anytime I turn it on or reboot, the screen stays black until I ctrl+alt+F4 to get into a shell. I'm trying to use KDE Plasma 5, but I'm willing to try other DEs if they might work better. I used an installer ISO with KDE on it and it was able to show the graphical displays and everything. Then after installing on my partition, I can't get a graphical display going.

Here is my configuration.nix (current channel is nixos/21.11):

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }:

{
  imports =
    [ # Include the results of the hardware scan.
      ./hardware-configuration.nix
    ];

  # Use the systemd-boot EFI boot loader.
  boot.loader.systemd-boot.enable = true;
  boot.loader.efi.canTouchEfiVariables = true;

  boot.kernelPackages = pkgs.linuxPackages_5_16;

  networking.hostName = "fins-thinkpad"; # Define your hostname.
  
  networking.networkmanager.enable = true;  # Easiest to use and most distros use this by default.

  # Nvidia drivers unfree
  nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;

  # Enable the X11 windowing system.
  services.xserver.enable = true;

  # Enable the Plasma 5 Desktop Environment.
  services.xserver.displayManager.sddm.enable = true;
  services.xserver.desktopManager.plasma5.enable = true;
  services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nvidia" ];
  hardware.opengl.enable = true;

  users.users.finley = {
    isNormalUser = true;
    extraGroups = [ "wheel" ]; # Enable ‘sudo’ for the user.
  };

  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    vim # Do not forget to add an editor to edit configuration.nix! The Nano editor is also installed by default.
    wget
    firefox
  ];

  system.stateVersion = "22.05"; # Did you read the comment?
}
```

And my `hardware-configuration.nix`:

```
{ config, lib, pkgs, modulesPath, ... }:

{
  imports =
    [ (modulesPath + "/installer/scan/not-detected.nix")
    ];

  boot.initrd.availableKernelModules = [ "xhci_pci" "thunderbolt" "nvme" "usb_storage" "sd_mod" "sdhci_pci" ];
  boot.initrd.kernelModules = [ ];
  boot.kernelModules = [ "kvm-intel" ];
  boot.extraModulePackages = [ ];

  fileSystems."/" =
    { device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/7e6bcba1-25e7-43f5-8dd2-1458d863c0c4";
      fsType = "ext4";
    };

  fileSystems."/boot" =
    { device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/19A7-C717";
      fsType = "vfat";
    };

  swapDevices =
    [ { device = "/dev/disk/by-uuid/14412169-fb90-4e0c-ae3f-735c817b8cf3"; }
    ];

  # The global useDHCP flag is deprecated, therefore explicitly set to false here.
  # Per-interface useDHCP will be mandatory in the future, so this generated config
  # replicates the default behaviour.
  networking.useDHCP = lib.mkDefault false;
  networking.interfaces.enp11s0.useDHCP = lib.mkDefault true;
  networking.interfaces.wlp9s0.useDHCP = lib.mkDefault true;

  powerManagement.cpuFreqGovernor = lib.mkDefault "powersave";
  hardware.cpu.intel.updateMicrocode = lib.mkDefault config.hardware.enableRedistributableFirmware;
  # high-resolution display
  hardware.video.hidpi.enable = lib.mkDefault true;
}
```

And the logs from display-manager are on this pastebin raw link: https://pastebin.com/raw/YycVPVVd

And here is the output of `lspci -k | grep -A3 'VGA'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a70 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 22d8
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 24b7 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 22d8
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Happy to post anymore logs or files if necessary and willing to try anything to get this working! Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a result of the integrated Intel graphics card not playing nice with the Nvidia card in my laptop somehow. Since the integrated graphics card can just be used with modesetting drivers, changing the configuration to the following fixes it:

```
services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "modesetting" ]
```

Instead of `[ "nvidia" ]`. Also, it's pretty simple to set up offloading between the integrated and Nvidia graphics cards using PRIME configuration in NixOS [as explained in the Wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nvidia#Nvidia_PRIME).